# Depreciated Code from Swift 2 to Swift 3

Tags: xcode, swift2, swift3

So I followed this tutorial on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uUTevJAhL3Q, and I can't figure out how to update the rest to Swift 3; I am relatively new at Swift and still learning, if anyone could help me out a bit that would be fantastic! I am trying to re-create a snapchat camera-view.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class CameraVC: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {


    var captureSession : AVCaptureSession?
    var stillImageOutput : AVCaptureStillImageOutput?
    var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    @IBOutlet var cameraView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        previewLayer?.frame = cameraView.bounds
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080

        var backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

        var error : NSError?
        var input = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera, error: &error)

        if (error == nil && captureSession?.canAddInput(input) != nil){

            captureSession?.addInput(input)

            stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
            stillImageOutput?.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]

            if (captureSession?.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) != nil){
                captureSession?.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

                previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
                previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
                captureSession?.startRunning()

            }


        }


    }
    @IBOutlet var tempImageView: UIImageView!


    func didPressTakePhoto(){

        if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput?.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo){
            videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
            stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: {
                (sampleBuffer, error) in

                if sampleBuffer != nil {


                    var imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                    var dataProvider  = CGDataProvider(data: imageData as! CFData)
                    var cgImageRef = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: kCGRenderingIntentDefault)

                    var image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)

                    self.tempImageView.image = image
                    self.tempImageView.isHidden = false

                }


            })
        }


    }


    var didTakePhoto = Bool()

    func didPressTakeAnother(){
        if didTakePhoto == true{
            tempImageView.isHidden = true
            didTakePhoto = false

        }
        else{
            captureSession?.startRunning()
            didTakePhoto = true
            didPressTakePhoto()

        }

    }

    func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        didPressTakeAnother()
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the exact errors your facing and what you tried?  I doubt anyone is going to go through and rewrite this code directly for you.

Comment: it is in relation to   var stillImageOutput : AVCaptureStillImageOutput? and how that effects the rest of the inputs that use that

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 introduced the idea of [error handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html) and most (if not all) of Apple's Foundation and Core APIs got updated so that instead of using capturing an error with the `inout &error` parameter the method `throws` and error.

So code that you used to write like this:

```
var error : NSError?
var input = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera, error: &error)
```

In Swift 3 is updated to drop the error parameter, and you use the new `do`, `try`, `catch` syntax:

```
do {
    var input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
    //... input was assigned without an error, you can use in the scope of this statement

}
catch {
    // an error occured attempting `AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)`
    print("an error occured")
}
```

Of if you prefer, the shorthand versions:

```
var input = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
// not safe: app will crash if AVCaptureDeviceInput fails 

var input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
// safer: input will be assigned as `nil` if AVCaptureDeviceInput fails
```

Next time you're converting from Swift 2 to Swift 3, try using Xcode's 'refactor' tool it does a pretty good job of automatically making these changes for you.

Comment: ps: next time when asking a question on overflow, don't forget to write the actual error that Xcode is giving you e.g. `Cannot invoke in initializer for type AVCaptureDeviceInput...` because that will help people help you a lot faster!